# Blazor c# - how to XmlDocument.load() a local file

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-webassembly, xmldocument

New to Blazor (web-assembly), so go easy :)

I would like to be able to select an xml file from local disk (in the region of 100mb in size), via InputFile and have it loaded in to XmlDocument so I can interrogate it.

Upon trying to load a file of this size, it crashes out on XmlDocument.load(). Unsure why.

I can get it to load smaller file sizes via a OpenReadStream and setting the maxAllowedSize to like 105000000 but they take a complete age in comparison to say loading it from a WPF c# app.

I'm unsure whether the stream is causing the slowness, or whether I'm missing something fundamental in accessing local disk files during the XmlDocument load process of this size?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

So basically, all i want to be able to do is something like this...

```
<InputFile OnChange="LoadFile">Select file...</InputFile> 

@{
private void LoadFile()
{
XmlDocument newXml = new XmlDocument();
newXml.load(ChosenFilePath); //ChosenFilePath or hardcoded path for testing purposes still fails i.e. @"C:\temp\TestFile.xml"
}

}
```

Comment: You can't directly access files from the disk from Blazor, as it's running inside a Browser context and that would be a major security flaw. Instead, you need to accept the `InputFileChangeEventArgs` and get the file(s) through that

Comment: Hey, thanks for your comment. I've actually tried this, and can access the file details, but again it errors when I attempt to load the e.File.Name in to XmlDocument.Load().

Now I know I'm in the right area, I'll try again. Thanks again for all your help, appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to accept the `InputFileChangeEventArgs` and get your file through it, that's relatively simple, your event handler should be this:

```cs
private void LoadFile(InputFileChangeEventArgs args)
{
    // The argument is to increase the maximum size, by default it only allows
    // you to open files less than or equal to 500KiB, the number below is 200MiB
    // Alternatively you could pass 'args.File.Size' to allow opening an arbitraily large file
    var fileStream = args.File.OpenReadStream(200 * 1024 * 1024);
    var newXml = new XmlDocument();
    newXml.Load(fileStream);
}
```

Comment: Thanks again MindSwipe. I must be doing something fundamentally wrong here as I've just tried implementing the method exactly as above, yet it still fails on newXml.Load(fileStream). 

Never mind, i'll plod on, thanks again for your time. Cheers

Comment: What's the error you're getting?

Comment: Dont actually appear to be getting any errors. When I step through each line (having previously selected a 5kb file) in VS, it gets to the load statement and then it simply returns to the browser. After the file is "loaded" is should write to a parameter saying its "completed" but never gets there! 

Obviously want to get this fixed, but trying out Blazor to see whether I should "upgrade" from my WPF C# based app to a Web based app via Blazor. The WPF app can load a 100mb file in around 1 second. I can't even load a 5kb file via blazor :( 

Thanks for your time, I'm sure I'll figure it out